# Delimiting a region of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a 560x560 numpy matrix, which I want to convert to a 28x28 one. 
Therefore, I want to subdivide it into regions with size 16x16, calculate the mean of each such regions and put that value in a new matrix.

Now I have:

```
import numpy as np

oldMat = ...                      #I load the 560x560 matrix
newMat = np.zeros((28,28))        #Initializes the new matrix of size 28x28

for i in range(0,560, 16):
    for j in range(0,560, 16):    #Loops over the top left corner of each region 
        sum = 0
        for di in range(16):
            for dj in range(16):  #Loops over the indices of the elements in each region
                sum += oldMat[i+di, j+dj]

        mean = sum/256            #Calculates the mean of the elements of each region
        newMat[i][j] = mean
```

Is there a faster way to do this? (I'm sure there is.)

Comment: I'm not following your logic, how do you intend to go from 560x560 --> 313,600 points to a 28x28 of 16x16, which corresponds to 200,704 points? Do you mean 28x28 of 20x20?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to reshape your matrix from `2D --> 4D`, then you can use `np.reshape()`:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

data = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(6,6))
```

Yields:

```
[[4 0 3 3 3 1]
 [3 2 4 0 0 4]
 [2 1 0 1 1 0]
 [1 4 3 0 3 0]
 [2 3 0 1 3 3]
 [3 0 1 1 1 0]]
```

Then reshape:

```
data.reshape((3,3,2,2))
```

Returns:

```
[[[[4 0]
   [3 3]]

  [[3 1]
   [3 2]]

  [[4 0]
   [0 4]]]


 [[[2 1]
   [0 1]]

  [[1 0]
   [1 4]]

  [[3 0]
   [3 0]]]
```